# Расположение легенды на субграфиках (subplots)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, python-3.6, dataframe

Продолжаем мучать свой лабораторный стенд.
Мы получаем три субграфика и счастливы. Вредничает препод - желает чтоб все подписи были с одной стороны. Победить не можем.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`plt.legend(loc = 'upper left')` - действует только на последний график.
и ругается - `No handles with labels found to put in legend`. и какое-то NONE торчит :)

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

plt.style.use('ggplot')


p = Path(r'C:\NET\Log\Data')

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep=';', header=None, usecols=[2,3,5],
                            names=['date','time',f.stem], index_col=['date','time'])
               for f in p.glob('*.trd')],
               axis=1)

df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.index.get_level_values(0) + ' ' + df.index.get_level_values(1)))


fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(16, 8));

plt.legend(loc = 'upper left')
df.filter(regex=r'^tmp').plot(ax=axes[0])
df.filter(regex=r'^press').plot(ax=axes[1], sharex=True)
df.filter(regex=r'^tok').plot(ax=axes[2], sharex=True)

ax_press = df.filter(regex=r'^freq2').plot(ax=axes[2], secondary_y=True)

axes[-1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M\n%d.%m.%Y'))

axes[0].set_ylabel('Температура')
axes[1].set_ylabel('Давление')
axes[2].set_ylabel('Ток мотора')
ax_press.set_ylabel('Частота')
axes[-1].set_xlabel('Время')
```

Набор данных - https://dropmefiles.com/W6C8m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

пример:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 1, figsize=(16, 8));

plt.legend(loc = 'upper left')
df.filter(regex=r'^tmp').plot(ax=axes[0])
df.filter(regex=r'^press').plot(ax=axes[1], sharex=True)
df.filter(regex=r'^freq').plot(ax=axes[2], sharex=True)
df.filter(regex=r'^tok').plot(ax=axes[3], sharex=True)

axes[-1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M\n%d.%m.%Y'))

axes[0].set_ylabel('Температура')
axes[1].set_ylabel('Давление')
axes[2].set_ylabel('Частота')
axes[3].set_ylabel('Ток мотора')
axes[-1].set_xlabel('Время')
```

чтобы задать позицию легенды для всех `subplots`:

```
for ax in axes:
    ax.legend(loc='upper left')

# automatically adjusts subplot params so that the subplot(s) fits in to the figure area
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на сделать сдвоенный график - частота-ток - пропадает подпись справа :(

Comment: @Ivan, а как лучше сдвоенный или четыре отдельных?

Comment: да не поймешь его - у него один день так другой так :(
хочет совмещенный частота-ток....

Comment: @Ivan, частота и ток - всегда будут по одному файлу или их может быть множество?

Comment: да по одному. каждый датчик или параметр один файл. контроллер так выдает логи.

Comment: @Ivan, я имел в виду количество датчиков тока и частоты - у вас по одному такому датчику?

Comment: да - моторчик один