# Заполнение столбца в DataFrame на основании формулы и вывод в график

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, python-3.6, dataframe

Пытаемся рисовать графики в лаборатории.

Имеем данные по частоте мотора. Как добавить в таблицу новый столбик заполненный вычисленными значения из столбика `freq2` умноженного на 60 и вывести его в график и обозвать обороты ?

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

plt.style.use('ggplot')


p = Path(r'C:\NET\Log\Data')

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep=';', header=None, usecols=[2,3,5],
                            names=['date','time',f.stem], index_col=['date','time'])
               for f in p.glob('*.trd')],
               axis=1)

df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.index.get_level_values(0) + ' ' + df.index.get_level_values(1)))


fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(16, 8));

plt.legend(loc = 'upper left')
df.filter(regex=r'^tmp').plot(ax=axes[0])
df.filter(regex=r'^press').plot(ax=axes[1], sharex=True)
df.filter(regex=r'^tok').plot(ax=axes[2], sharex=True)

ax_press = df.filter(regex=r'^freq2').plot(ax=axes[2], secondary_y=True)

axes[-1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M\n%d.%m.%Y'))

axes[0].set_ylabel('Температура')
axes[1].set_ylabel('Давление')
axes[2].set_ylabel('Ток мотора')
ax_press.set_ylabel('Частота')
axes[-1].set_xlabel('Время')
```

Данные [тут](https://dropmefiles.com/W6C8m).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить столбец в DataFrame очень просто:

```
In [54]: df['Обороты'] = df['freq2'] * 60

In [55]: df
Out[55]:
                     freq2   press12   press22   press42   press52   ...         tmp72       tmp82       tmp92  tok_motora2  Обороты
2018-03-08 09:35:52   0.00  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   ...      0.000000    0.000000    0.000000     0.000000      0.0
2018-03-08 09:35:53   1.67 -0.134831  0.123405  0.012000  0.010572   ...     70.759918  144.246078   36.773521     0.000000    100.2
2018-03-08 09:35:54   1.67 -0.134831  0.123405  0.012000  0.010572   ...     70.759918  144.270630   36.773521     0.000000    100.2
2018-03-08 09:35:55   1.67 -0.140544  0.123405  0.012000  0.010572   ...     70.759918  144.270630   36.748970     0.000000    100.2
2018-03-08 09:35:56   1.67 -0.140544  0.123405  0.012000  0.010572   ...     70.759918  144.270630   36.748970     0.000000    100.2
2018-03-08 09:35:57   1.67 -0.140544  0.123405  0.009858  0.011286   ...     70.759918  144.295181   36.773521     0.000000    100.2
2018-03-08 09:35:58   1.67 -0.140544  0.123405  0.009858  0.011286   ...     70.759918  144.295181   36.773521     0.000000    100.2
2018-03-08 09:35:59   1.67 -0.139830  0.123405  0.009858  0.011286   ...     70.759918  144.295181   36.773521     0.000000    100.2
2018-03-08 09:36:00   1.67 -0.139830  0.122691  0.012000  0.011286   ...     70.759918  144.319702   36.773521     0.000000    100.2
2018-03-08 09:36:01   1.67 -0.139830  0.122691  0.012000  0.011286   ...     70.759918  144.319702   36.773521     0.000000    100.2
...                    ...       ...       ...       ...       ...   ...           ...         ...         ...          ...      ...
2018-03-08 14:31:24  49.00  0.549742  0.452620  0.021998  0.024140   ...     73.536102  141.545776  111.866852    77.400002   2940.0
2018-03-08 14:31:25  49.00  0.549742  0.452620  0.020570  0.023426   ...     73.536102  141.545776  111.866852    77.400002   2940.0
2018-03-08 14:31:26  49.00  0.549742  0.452620  0.020570  0.023426   ...     73.536110  141.545776  111.866852    77.400002   2940.0
2018-03-08 14:31:27  49.00  0.551170  0.452620  0.020570  0.023426   ...           NaN  141.545776  111.866852    77.400002   2940.0
2018-03-08 14:31:34  49.00       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   ...           NaN         NaN         NaN          NaN   2940.0
2018-03-08 14:31:35    NaN  0.551170  0.452620  0.020570  0.023426   ...     73.536110  141.521225  111.866852          NaN      NaN
2018-03-08 14:31:36  49.00  0.549742  0.451906  0.021998  0.023426   ...     73.527199  141.545776  111.891403          NaN   2940.0
2018-03-08 14:31:37  49.00  0.549742  0.451906  0.021284  0.023426   ...     73.527199  141.521225  111.891403          NaN   2940.0
2018-03-08 14:31:38  49.00       NaN       NaN  0.021284  0.023426   ...     73.527191  141.521225         NaN          NaN   2940.0
2018-03-08 14:31:54    NaN  0.549742  0.451906       NaN       NaN   ...           NaN         NaN  111.866852          NaN      NaN
```

еще несколько способов добавить столбец на основании другого столбца:

[df.assign()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = df.assign(Обороты=df['freq2'] * 60)
```

[df.eval()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.eval.html)

```
df = df.eval("Обороты = freq2 * 60")
```

PS как рисовать графики [вы уже знаете](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/867755/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85-subplots) ;)

Comment: блин - почти так и делали :) - только зачем-то  df.assign брали ! Спасибо тебе - спасаешь в очередной раз !

Comment: @Ivan, можно и `df.assign` использовать: `df = df.assign(Обороты=df['freq2'] * 60)`

Comment: Ура - получилось :)